# Yii2: Join condition parameters are null when using "with"

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I have a many to many relation:

```
Parent(id) <- Link(parent,child,sort) -> Product(sku)
```

I want to get a *sorted* list of Products from the Parent model

On the parent model I have a couple of functions:

```
public function getLinksDown()
{
    return $this->hasMany( DBLink::className(), ['parent' => 'id'])
        ->from(['linksDown' => DBLink::tableName()]);
}

public function getProducts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(DBProduct::className(), ['sku' => 'child'])
        ->from(['products' => DBProduct::tableName()])
        ->via('linksDown')
        ->innerJoin(
            ['linx' => DBLink::tableName()],
            'linx.child = products.sku AND linx.parent=:parent',
            [':parent' => $this->id]
        )
        ->orderBy(['linx.order' => SORT_ASC]);
}
```

If I call the relation directly it works fine.

```
$model = Parent::findOne(1234);
$products = $model->products;
```

Products is a list of products sorted correctly.

If the relation is called as a part of a "with" it fails, $this->id will be null which means no products are returned.

```
Parent::find()->with('products')->all();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much head scratching, I have decided the only solution, is to abandon the Many to Many relation where I need a sorted list of products, and do something like this:

```
$model = Parent::find()->where(['id' => 1234])->with('linksDown.products')->one();
```

and reference each product through the linksDown relation, instead of directly from the parent model.

```
foreach( $model->linksDown as $link ) {
    dosomethingwith($link->product);
}
```

In order to make this work the sort will need to be applied to the linksDown relation:

```
public function getLinksDown()
{
    return $this->hasMany( DBLink::className(), ['parent' => 'id'])
        ->from(['linksDown' => DBLink::tableName()])
        ->orderBy([linksDown.order => SORT_ASC]);
}
```